# Cilium installation problem after kubeadm init for a 2 node Kubernetes cluster in local VMs

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, cilium

I want to setup a 2 node Kubernetes cluster in local VMs using VMware. I have set up the control node using the following command:

`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.1.1.0/24 --apiserver-advertise-address IP_ADDRESS_OF_NODE_FROM_IFCONFIG`

Then i wanted to install cilium as a CNI but it failed with the following error:

```
Using Cilium version 1.14.4
Skipping auto kube-proxy detection

Error: Unable to install Cilium: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://localhost:8080/version": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

The installation was done through terminal using the following commands:

```
curl -LO https://github.com/cilium/cilium-cli/releases/latest/download/cilium-linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar xzvfC cilium-linux-amd64.tar.gz /usr/local/bin
rm cilium-linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo cilium install
```

I have also run a cilium status command, after the installation failure, and got this output:

```
    /¯¯\
 /¯¯\__/¯¯\    Cilium:             1 errors
 \__/¯¯\__/    Operator:           disabled
 /¯¯\__/¯¯\    Envoy DaemonSet:    disabled (using embedded mode)
 \__/¯¯\__/    Hubble Relay:       disabled
    \__/       ClusterMesh:        disabled

Containers:            cilium             
                       cilium-operator    
Cluster Pods:          0/0 managed by Cilium
Helm chart version:    
Errors:                cilium    cilium    daemonsets.apps "cilium" not found
```

What can I try next?